# Do Loop in SAS SQL

Tags: sas

I want to create Age variable for 2012 to 2022 by using the condition, I can do it one by one by using YEAR(calculated td-1), YEAR(calculated td), YEAR(calculated td+1),YEAR(calculated td+2) but it is lengthy process.There is year in table2 which is duplicate.  Please help me to do in a single step.

Here is sample code:

`proc sql;`

`create table Forecast1(DROP=td) as`

`select  T1.*`

`,date() as td`

```
,case 
when (YEAR(calculated td))- year(T1.Engine)<=10 then '0-10'
when (YEAR(calculated td))- year(T1.Engine)<=20 then '10-20' 
when (YEAR(calculated td))- year(T1.Engine)<=35 then '20-35' 
else '35p' end as Age_2013 format=$char5.
from gopi1.FLEET_MASTER  T1   
left join gopi1.ANNUAL_FH_AVERAGE T2
on T1.Model=T2.Model and T1.Age_bracket=T2.Age_bracket
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're in SAS then you should do this in the data step.  You could do it in a view and then read that into SQL, if you prefer.

```
data fleet_master_vw/view=fleet_master_vw;
set fleet_master;
array ageyr age_2012 - age_2022;
do _t = 1 to dim(ageyr);
  ageyr[_t] = (your age calculation);
end;
drop _t;
run;

proc sql;
 ... your sql stuff, using fleet_master_vw as your source dataset ...
```

I assume `fleet_master` contains your ages - change to the other one if needed.